# Can't delete folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I'm trying to delete a folder in Windows 7 and get a perplexing error message: "Could not find this item:  This is no longer located in G:\Graphics.  Verify the item's location and try again.

I can see the folder -- I can find it.  I just can't delete it.

I also get a second error message (sometimes) when I click on the folder: G:\Graphics 2009-11-17 refers to a location that is unavailable...this information might have been moved to a different location.

I'm using Windows 7; this folder is on an external hard drive.  I've emptied the folder (there were items in it); I've scanned that external hard drive for errors.  Trying to rename the folder yields the same enigmatic error message.

Is there a way to delete this folder?

Answer (score 21):

Open Command Prompt, use `dir /x` to get the 8.3 name of the folder which cannot be deleted, and then 
use `rd` with the 8.3 name of the folder, and it should be gone.

If this doesn't work, ensure first that the folder is empty.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Not only did I have to rd with the 8.3 name, but there were a bunch of hidden sub-folders with content which had to be deleted first: 'del /s /f /q *.*' and then 'rd /s /q eight.three'.

Comment: You may have to rename the folder first and then delete it. So first open a cmd and type `cd` then drag the parent folder in cmd (this will add the path), then press `enter`. Then type `dir /x` and `enter`. Then type `ren Folder~1 newname`  (replace `Folder~1`with your folder 8.3 name whici you can find in the long list created by the previous command), press `enter`. Finally type `del newname` and press `enter` src=  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-files/error-could-not-find-this-item-this-is-no-longer/70969fd0-4afe-43f5-a50e-c1e59ac227d0?auth=1

Answer (score 7):

You can try [Unlocker](http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/) if you experience these kind of issues in the future.  Windows is known to lock certain files/folder and refuse access to edit/delete them from time to time; [Unlocker](http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/) is a handly little program that can help rename/move/delete unresponsive files/folders.

Comment: +1, Unlocker's a great tool. It's come in handy for me many times over the years.

Comment: This worked, but watch out for bundled malware that's default-checked in the installer.

Answer (score 6):

1. Download 7zip
2. Browse to folder
3. Right-click rename (successful)
4. Close 7zip
5. Browse to folder > right-click delete

Comment: I finally had to delete the file from MacOS to but it was not possible before using this trick

Answer (score 5):

yes. Boot into Linux using any of the live CDs, I would recommend Ubuntu and delete that damn folder

Comment: Haha, I remember creating a *ton* of nested directories one time in Windows to mess with a friend, then I couldn't delete them from Windows.  I think I ended up doing it in Linux.

Comment: Yeah...I virus clean all my suspicious thumb drives in Ubuntu before shoving them up in Windows

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Do a `dir /x /ad` to get the 8.3 name of the folder (it will look like docume~1), then do a `rd folder* /s` (you may even truncate it more like `rd fol* /s` if there are no other directories with similar names).

If this does not work, the run `chkdsk /f` (maybe a couple of times even, but check your Event Viewer>Windows Logs>Application Log to see if there are still a lot of errors. http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/96938-check-disk-chkdsk-read-event-viewer-log.html screenshots 6 or 8). Then try the rd command with the 8.3 again as above.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your computer, and then deleting the folder.

When you restart your computer the folder might even be gone.
It might have already been deleted, but Explorer was showing a cached image.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget if the file type has been corrupted, the extension may not appear in the 8.3 name, if for example you have something like this:

- `FILENAME.EXT`
- `FILENAME.EXT`
- `FILENAME`
- `FILENAME.EXT`

and the one missing its extension is the one you can't delete, use the `del` command and the file name and add four spaces, then hit *Enter*.

For example:

```
del FILENAME__________
```

The `____________` at the end there is just to show the four spaces added.

This just worked for me on a file that was corrupted during download.