# Delete a folder when "Could not find this item" (when the folder ends with a space, maybe?)

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't delete folder in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/72280/cant-delete-folder-in-windows-7)

I have a folder that appears to be mildly corrupted or something in Windows 7: Windows shows it, but if I try to delete it, I get this:

> Could not find this item
>
> This is no longer located in [path]. Verify the item's location and
>   try again.

This has continued beyond reboot, `chkdsk`, `chkdsk -F` and reboot.  I've tried from the GUI and a command window. It's still happening even if I do something like

```
rd "folder[space]"
```

in an elevated command window: I receive "The system cannot find the file specified."

I have a pretty good idea what the issue may be: the folder name is ended with a space (it was created by a script).  Since Windows 7 tries to prevent this from happening, it can't imagine the possibility that the folder has a space in it, so I think it's trying to delete "`folder`" instead of "`folder[space]`".  If this *is* the case, how do I fix it?