# How do I delete a folder that can't be deleted normal way?

Tags: windows, user-folders

I was working on my code and tried to run a migration against a my local database. Migration couldn't be applied but this folder was created:
[image: picture-1]
[image: picture-2]

Soon after, my whole solution couldn't be loaded and I cannot still delete this folder. What do I do? Where did it come from?

I tried the following:

1) Reboot

2) Safe boot

3) Open CMD with administrator rights and run `rmdir "'.."` but that gives me an error stating that such path doesn't exist

Comment: Have you tried rebooting first?

Comment: @DavidPostill yes, I also tried to safe boot but that didn't work either

Comment: So please [edit] the question and add that information.

Comment: You can get Unlocker 1.92 (MajorGeeks) and use that to delete the items in the folder and then delete the folder.  Unlocker removes locking handles and you often have to restart after deleting files.

Comment: Can you try moving the folder to the desktop or elsewhere and deleting it from there?

Comment: @Meow_ly no, it doesn't allow me to do that (to move the folder). Gives the same error as in the picture.

Comment: @John are you sure this Unlocker is safe? I downloaded the exe file and ran it through VirusTotal that indicated this file as a virus.

Comment: Did you get it from Major Geeks?  I have been using it for years and it is fine. Not a virus. Try also Softpedia.  I have always found it to be a useful tool

Comment: You probably have to use command prompt and get in from a different stream. Can you delete the folder if you use the following path? `\\.\D:\Projects\blur\blur\Infrastructure\'..` so basically preceed the path with \\.\

Comment: Are you sure about the folder name? If it contains a backspace or something similar you don't see what you should enter as folder name to delete. I would copy all useful files and (try to) delete the parent folder recursively.

Comment: @harper your solution worked. thank you

Comment: Might try one of these alternative delete methods: https://superuser.com/questions/78434/how-to-delete-directories-with-path-names-too-long-for-normal-delete/78458

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't delete folder in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/72280/cant-delete-folder-in-windows-7)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is to "cd" into the folder's grandparent and recursively delete the parent folder by running `rmdir <folder> /s /q`.

Comment: Downvoted because you propose an command that is not supported by Windows although the question is tagged with "Windows".

Comment: @harper my apologies, I have turned on the possibility of using linux commands on my windows machine and forgot those commands are not available by default

Comment: No need to apologise. Take it as an encouragement to improve your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I got past similar stuff with:

cd \just\above\the\problem\folder

rem dir should show the problem folder name

rmdir /s /q "problem folder"

Comment: "rm" unknown command or file name. This is a Windows question.

Comment: Sorry, the command is "rmdir".  Any doubts, try rmdir /? to see the command line optioins.

Comment: So, why not use ***[edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1542939/edit)*** and add this correction in the answer?

Comment: Maybe because you've only got 5 minutes to edit a comment...?

Comment: @Didier They're talking about an answer, not a comment.

Comment: And you woke me up for *this*...?!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Unlocker Program.

> You can download at : 
> https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Unlocker.shtml#download

After you install the program:
 1. Open the program.
 2. The Browse File or Folder Window will be shown. Locate this to your undeletable folder. Then click OK.
    [Browse File or Folder Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL9ob.png)

3. On the action selection, select Delete and press OK.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhhbi.png)